# Windows Live OAuth access XBox Live Info

Tags: oauth, xbox-one, windows-live

So, I'm working on a website, and I want users to be able to log in with their xbox account to link their gamer tag to my site. I can use oauth like this:

[image: mysite]

But, I can't figure out how to get xbox live permissions. Other sites that do this have permissions like this:

[image: perms]

How do I get this permissions which allow me to get info from an xbox account, like the gamertag? On the [permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx) page I don't see xbox anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by using Xbox Live API,
Sign up for the **Xbox Live Creators Program**
and then you can call the Xbox Live REST endpoints directly to ask the user to authorize your application.

The official API documentation provides excellent examples to help you progress at a quick pace. Also you can refer to [Windows UWP for Xbox Live Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/introduction-to-xbox-live-apis) for some detailed info.

---

Sources:
[Xbox Live Creators Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/xboxlive)
[Github Repo of Xbox Live API](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-api)

Comment: For future readers, if you're a student you can get a free Xbox live developer account through Microsoft Imagine, which you need for the Xbox Live Creators Program.

Comment: On the official xbox website it says we can use it for game development. Is it allowed for web apps also?

Comment: @ex0mak3r can you point me to where these specific rest endpoints are for authenticating? I have apps created but can't find any good examples of specific rest endpoints for authenticating.

Comment: Would anyone mind providing a modern and more complete answer here?  I've spent many hours exploring the creators program, signing up, creating an app, etc, with little success.  Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: @Patrick hey Patrick, I've also been looking into this for some time now, did you finally achieve anything? I'm about to enroll into the Creators Program, but I'm unsure if I should pay the registration fee, so before trying to do it, I would like to know if it is worth it :)

Comment: @nightsurgex2: did you guys ever find a solution? please help, stuck in same problem...