# Creating a way to log in/register an account on a website through Xbox Live

Tags: oauth, xbox, windows-live

I'm trying to find a way to allow users on my website to log in/create accounts by using their own Xbox Live Accounts through OAuth. I have read a bit here "[Windows Live OAuth access XBox Live Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758250/windows-live-oauth-access-xbox-live-info)" that you can use the $20 "Xbox Live Creators Program" but I am skeptical. Other places I have read say you need special permission from Xbox in order to make this work, claiming that Xbox does not give out their API to anyone. I've looked into it but haven't found much luck. Has anyone had experience doing this?

Comment: You're "skeptical"? Have you tried the accepted solution to that question?

Comment: @chb "Xbox Live Creators Program" has to do with game development rather than API.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do what you're after without signing up for XBox Live Creator's Program.

The [OpenXBox](https://github.com/OpenXbox) project offers, among other things, [Python executables and code](https://github.com/OpenXbox/xbox-webapi-python) for authenticating a user using a Microsoft OAuth-based service.

Comment: Not too sure about how Python works, but am willing to pursue it for this project I am working on. Is there anyway I could authenticate users through PHP with this in any way?

Comment: @RichardShepherd Not in a way that wouldn't be a horrible kludge... You could, however, look at the Python code and create equivalent PHP code; Python is a very legible and intuitive language. Have a look at [this post and the chosen response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116596/converting-python-code-to-php).